# gtk combobox: add items with two fields

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygtk

I would like to add items to combo-box widget with two fields so when the user selecting an item, he will see one field, and the program will see both of the fields that have been selected.

Here is my code:

```
slist = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
slist.append(['item_name1', 'item_id1'])
slist.append(['item_name2', 'item_id2'])
slist.append(['item_name3', 'item_id3'])

self.combobox = gtk.ComboBox(model=slist)

cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.combobox.pack_start(cell)
self.combobox.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 1)
self.combobox.set_model(slist)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example snippet is already setup with a model holding two columns of data while the view is only displaying a single column. To retrieve both columns of data from something like a selection, you can use "get_active_iter()" in combination with a "changed" signal to pull out an entire row of data:

```
def on_selection_changed(combo):
    itr = combo.get_active_iter()
    print(slist.get_value(itr, 0), slist.get_value(itr, 1))

combobox.connect('changed', on_selection_changed)
```

See also: http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--get-active-iter